# Calendar reminder not working in Loki 0.4

Tags: release-loki

First of all thanks for the wonderful OS that Loki 0.4 is. I have been using it for the last few days and one of the issues i have faced is that the calendar app is not remembering the reminder function and does not pass this info to notification. I have also read that this is an outstanding issue. Is there a temporary fix for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is issue is known and has already been reported as a bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/maya/+bug/1420633

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar notifications daemon isn't installed by default. You can try to install from terminal:

```
sudo apt install maya-calendar-daemon
```

Comment: Installing the notifications daemon does not fix this issue.